# Queued tasks in thread pool are exiting, not being released back into pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, tcpclient, maui

I'm writing a C# Blazor MAUI app and am trying to perform some automated background tasks. Every 30 seconds, my applications scans the configuration to perform a connection test on a set of user-defined servers.

```
public static bool CanConnect(string host, int port, TimeSpan timeout) {
    try {
        using (var client = new TcpClient()) {
            var result = client.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null);
            var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
            client.EndConnect(result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Success! {host}:{port}");
            return success;
        }
    } catch {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Failed connecting to {host}:{port}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When my scheduler begins queuing up these tasks, I notice a very slight (but noticeable) hiccup on the GUI.

```
clusters.AsParallel()
        .ForAll(item => item.Status = ClusterIsAccessible(item) ? Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Online : Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Offline);
```

I believe the hiccup is a result of threads being created. I am noticing that when the jobs complete, the threads that are used to scan the connections will exit / timeout after 20-25s.

```
The thread 0x225c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4d2c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7c28 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6724 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x822c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x849c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5a24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x86ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8840 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x22f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x74e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7550 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8b80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4d48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x14a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5ed0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

My thought was that LINQ isn't using a thread pool but rather initializing new threads for each task.

To try and force the jobs onto the existing C# thread pool, I rewrote the iteration logic to use `ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(...)` but this also resulted in threads exiting and a slight hiccup when threads were being created.

```
clusters.ForEach((item) => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    item.Status = ClusterIsAccessible(item) ? Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Online : Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Offline;
}));
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to create unnecessary threads when there are already threads waiting for work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `WaitOne` is blocking a threadpool thread, which means a new one will be created after a short wait. The threadpool will continue creating more and more threads just to satisfy your requests, because each one keeps getting blocked.

Instead, you should use `async` `await`, which allows the threadpool thread to go off and do other things until the response comes back

```cs
public static async Task<bool> CanConnect(string host, int port, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    try
    {
        using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(host, port, cancel.Token);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Success! {host}:{port}");
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Failed connecting to {host}:{port}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you call it not using `Parallel.ForEach` but using `Task.WaitAll`

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(
    clusters.Select(async item =>
        item.Status = (await ClusterIsAccessible(item)) ? Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Online : Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Offline)
  );
```

If you want to limit the number of tasks running at once, you can do this

```cs
var running = new List<Task>();
var completed = new List<Task>();

foreach (var cluster in clusters)
{
    if (running.Count == YourMaxCount)
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(running);
        running.Remove(completedTask);
        completed.Add(completedTask);
    }
    running.Add(Task.Run(async item =>
        item.Status = (await ClusterIsAccessible(item)) ? Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Online : Cluster.ConnectionStatus.Offline));
}

await Task.WhenAll(running);
completed.AddRange(running);
```

Comment: I made the changes recommended here but still noticing that threads are starting & exiting. I believe the number of threads exiting are much smaller but they are still exiting. Perhaps its unavoidable?

Comment: How would I cap the number of threads allowed to execute simultaneously? I think this is where my hiccup is deriving from.

Comment: There will always be a certain amount of extra threads created if you run a lot of these at the same time. But performance should be massively increased this way.